# Align drop-down submenu in navigation to the same height as its parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, submenu

I try to align drop-down submenu to the same level as its parent. I spend few hours solve this issue, but I still don't know how to go about that.

The blue buttons are navigation links when I click on one of them, dark-blue sub-menu appears, then when I click on a link inside dark-blue menu a pink sub-menu appears. Problem is that the pink sub-menu would appear at the same height as the li element that I clicked on. I want to have the pink sub-menu always appear at the top, aligned with the dark-blue menu.

I hope you understand. I attach 2 pictures. I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Here is a link to the website. http://help.miloslacko.sk/ You can see the menu when you click on a link "01 SOCIALNE VECI MPSVR SR".

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vuw2f.jpg)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2spYB.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `position` property of `.wsmenu-submenu li` to `static`.

It is currently set to `position: relative`, which forces the children that are `absolute` anywhere beneath it to base their top off of it. Instead, allow the overall container (`.wsmenu-submenu video-container`) to be the nearest `relative` parent so that your `absolute` children base their position off of that.

NOTE: `position: absolute` will also act as an anchor for `absolute` children, so you don't need to change anything else.